# How many filaments are there in the observable universe?

Tags: cosmology, universe, observable-universe, galaxy-clusters

How many filaments are there in the observable universe? I couldn't find any list on Wikipedia.

Comment: -1 What research have you done to try to find an answer? eg Have you googled your title? What did you learn from doing that?

Comment: https://forum.cosmoquest.org/showthread.php?140620-How-many-galaxy-filaments-are-there-in-the-observable-Universe

Comment: Just not found in Wikipedia and Stack overflow

Comment: The problem is that filaments are not well defined structures.  There is a hazy transition between filaments and somewhat aligned galaxy clusters to random spots and sheets, so there is not going to be a crisp answer.

Comment: Have you done anything more sophisticated than looking up Wikipedia?  It's a good primary source have you consulted additional resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the DEEP2 Survey, which covers a volume of $\sim15\times10^6\,\mathrm{Mpc}^3$, [Choi et al. 2010](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.3239) find of the order 30-100 filaments, depending on the smoothing length of the Gaussian kernel used for smoothing the density field (this technicality has to do with the fact that filaments are not really well-defined, but become more discernible when the observed field is smoothed).

With a radius of roughly $R=46.3\,\mathrm{Gpc}$, the total volume of the observable Universe is $V = 4\pi (46.3\,\mathrm{Gpc})^3/3$, i.e.roughly $750,000$ times larger than the surveyed volume.

If DEEP2 is moderately representative for the rest of the Universe, the total number of filaments in the observable Universe is of the order $\mathbf{20}$**–**$\mathbf{75}$ **million**.